# finding probability finding good fuse

Tags: probability

There are $8$ good and $4$ bad fuses in a box. If $3$ are drawn at random, what is the probability that all will be good.

How i can solve this question when $3$ are drawn at random ?

Comment: This is the same problem as ones you have asked before. Two ways: (i) $\binom{8}{3}/\binom{12}{3}$ or (faster in this case, but messy in more complicated cases) (ii) $\frac{8}{12}\cdot\frac{7}{11}\cdot\frac{6}{10}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are exactly $\binom{8}{3}$ ways of choosing three good fuses while there are $\binom{8+4}{3}$ ways of choosing 3 fuses (from all possible fuses), hence your probability is $\frac{\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{8+4}{3}}$

or another approach - you can count it step-by-step, althought that's usually more cumbersome:
probability of the first fuse being good is $\frac{8}{12}$, probability of the second being good given the first one we picked was good is $\frac{7}{11}$ and for the third one it's $\frac{6}{10}$ hence your answer is $\frac{8}{12} \cdot \frac{7}{11} \cdot \frac{6}{10}$